# WordPress Mysql Query and Duplicates

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i've a problem with mysql query on my wordpress database.

I've custom fields Country and City.

At moment I have this query that show all the cities of "UK" Country

```
$querystr = "
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value DESC
";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

This is the query with php foreach that show all the cities

```
  <?php

 $querystr = "
 SELECT wposts.* 
 FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
 WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
 AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
 AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
 AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>

  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'city', true) ?> <br />

  <?php endforeach; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

This query listed all the UK City grabs the data from my WordPress Custom Field "City".

This query returns a list of Cities like:

```
Aberdeen
Aberdeen
Aberdeen
Aberdeen
Aberdeen
Belfast
Belfast
Belfast
Belfast
Belfast
Birchington
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Birmingham
Blackpool
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Bournemouth
Brighton
    Brighton
```

etc.!!!

as you can see there are duplicates of "city" field value, I need to show once the city and get a list like

```
      Aberdeen
      Aberdeen
      Belfast
      Birchington
      Birmingham
      Blackpool
      Bournemouth
      Brighton
      Bristol
```

How can I get this?
Thnks to everyone !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $querystr = "
 SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(     
 SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.post_id
 FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
 WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
 AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
 AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
 AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ) AND meta_key ='city'
 ";
 $cities = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 <?php if ($cities ): ?>

  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($cities as $c): ?>    
    <?php echo $c->meta_value; ?> <br />    
  <?php endforeach; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT after SELECT. It will remove the duplicates

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
";
```